# Sum within a foreach loop based on array with different group

Tags: php

I'm trying to take successful array results and start doing calculations on values based on another value in the array.

To start with, I want to sum every quantity 'TotalQTY' for each customer 'CSTNOC' in these arrays.

The array is printing fine but I'm getting undefined index errors in my last foreach loop.

I feel like this is simple enough but I'm not sure if my array isn't structure properly of if it's an issue with my loop.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [CSTNOC] => 1976
        [FRAMEC] => 1051
        [COVR1C] => 1150
        [COLR1C] => 99
        [START_DATE] => 2018-03-02
        [TOTALQTY] => 2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [CSTNOC] => 5400
        [FRAMEC] => 1051
        [COVR1C] => 1150
        [COLR1C] => 99
        [START_DATE] => 2017-11-10
        [TOTALQTY] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [CSTNOC] => 5400
        [FRAMEC] => 1051
        [COVR1C] => 1150
        [COLR1C] => 99
        [START_DATE] => 2017-04-07
        [TOTALQTY] => 2
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [CSTNOC] => 5400
        [FRAMEC] => 1051
        [COVR1C] => 1150
        [COLR1C] => 99
        [START_DATE] => 2018-02-09
        [TOTALQTY] => 2
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [CSTNOC] => 11316
        [FRAMEC] => 1051
        [COVR1C] => 1150
        [COLR1C] => 99
        [START_DATE] => 2017-03-03
        [TOTALQTY] => 1
    )
```

I basically want these results for an excel report purpose:

```
CSTNOC    |    TotalQTY
1976      |        2
5400      |        5
11316     |        1
```

This is the portion of the script:

```
$dealerQuery = "
        SELECT
              cstnoc,
              framec,
              covr1c,
              colr1c,
              cast(Left(extd2d, 4)||'-'||substring(extd2d,5,2)||'-'||substring(extd2d, 7,2) as date) as start_date,
              sum(orqtyc) as TotalQTY
          from table
            where cstnoc = {$skuRow['dealer_id']}
            AND framec = {$skuRow['frame']}
              AND colr1c = {$skuRow['color']}
              AND covr1c =  {$skuRow['cover']}
              AND extd2d >= " . str_replace('-', '', $skuRow['start_date']) . "
        group by cstnoc, framec,covr1c,colr1c,extd2d
    ";

    $dealerRslt = odbc_exec($DB2Conn, $dealerQuery);

    foreach($skuResult as $skuRow){
        while($dealerRow = odbc_fetch_array($dealerRslt)){

                $dealerResult[] = $dealerRow;
                $sum = 0;
                foreach($dealerResult['cstnoc'] as $dealerRow){
                    $sum += $dealerRow['TotalQTY'];
                }
                echo $sum;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you looping `$skuResult`, you never use `$skuRow`?  You could probably `SUM` this in the query, but for PHP:

```
while($dealerRow = odbc_fetch_array($dealerRslt)){
    if(!isset($dealerResult[$dealerRow['cstnoc']])) {        
        $dealerResult[$dealerRow['cstnoc']] = 0;
    }
    $dealerResult[$dealerRow['cstnoc']] += $dealerRow['TotalQTY'];
}
```

Then you can loop to display:

```
foreach($dealerResult as $cstnoc => $total) {
    echo "$cstnoc = $total";
}
```

Your query shows lowercase `cstnoc` but your result array shows Uppercase `CSTNOC`, so use whichever it really is.

Comment: Think column names are all upercase.

Comment: Your first version was fine, you actually don't need to check if an array element exists before adding a value to it (no error/warning afaik), but maybe it makes the intent clearer.

Comment: @NigelRen: They are in output but code and query shows lower.  Edited.

Comment: Just when they use `$DB2Conn`, I assume it's a DB2 connection, from what I've read it always returns column names in uppercase, but as long as OP is aware then it's OK.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @AbraCadaver I do use the skuResult but it's higher in the script and I didn't paste it in here. Basically, I do that do perform the db2 query per sku. But this solution looks great, I'm giving it a go now

Comment: @xander: No, check again.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same variable $dealerRow twice.
On:

```
while($dealerRow = odbc_fetch_array($dealerRslt)){
```

and in

```
foreach($dealerResult['cstnoc'] as $dealerRow){
```

try using another name inside the foreach.

Answer (score 0):

Simple `foreach` will do the trick.

```
$new = array();
foreach($arr as $k=>$v){
    $new[$v['CSTNOC']] = isset($new[$v['CSTNOC']]) ? $new[$v['CSTNOC']] + $v['TOTALQTY'] : $v['TOTALQTY'];
}
print_r($new);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/mPtDX)